# jQuery check file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I make ajax calls to the file /ajax.php

It gives me some data.

How do I check inside ajax.php, was this file directly opened in browser or by a true ajax call?

Comment: You should use POST ajax request

Comment: Just curious, but why should it make a difference?

Comment: @hughes don't want to see rip of my js

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be your answer. There is literally *no way* that you can stop people from seeing it, apart from extreme obfuscation.  Doesn't matter if it's done in GET or POST, if you're sending it to the user the user can see it.

Comment: @hughes part of the script is working on the php side. People can't rip php (without cracking the site), only js.

Comment: Any rendered document sent by the webserver is sent by the webserver. All the JS on a website is at all times rendered by the webserver. There is absolutely NO way in any capacity what-so-ever to even attempt to secure a javascript from being read. None. Regardless of what type of file it comes from, or how you request it. It just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty answer is like, you can't make it sure 100%. An "AJAX" request still is a normal *HTTP request*. Probably the best way to somewhat verify that is to set a custom *HTTP header* for which you have to check on the server side.

For instance, it's a common practice to add a `X-Requested-With` header to the HTTP request if it was an ajax request. jQuery for instance puts that header in all its request under the hood.

Comment: nice thought, but how can we check header of the request inside ajax.php? Can you please show some example? Have no idea how to do this

Comment: Since the OP is trying to use this as a form of security, I just want to point out that it's no problem for someone to add `X-Requested-With` to their own request. This won't stop people from seeing your response.

Comment: @hughes: I thought that was covered by my very first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual way PHP developers do this is to pass a flag to the server during the ajax request.

The usual flag I've seen has been: `ajax: true`

```
$.ajax({
url : "/ajax.php",
type: "POST", // If you want to send the data as a POST rather than GET
data:  ({ajax: true})
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the best way to make sure this was a true ajax request would be to use tools like firebug, fiddler or the network tab in the google chrome developer tools. you can then observer the traffic between your browser and the server, contents of the traffic etc..

Comment: I wanna see how php accesses firebug.

Comment: php doesn't access firebug, firebug is a browser plugin for firefox that you can use the debug your javascript, ajax calls, css, etc. it's mainly a very useful tool for debugging your client side code rather than server side.

Comment: Oh, so you cannot access the firebug console with php ? probably node.js can do it !!!!!!